# Question regarding a repeated STR.W instructions in ARM assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

What's the result of these instructions?
(Any suggestions how I could answer this myself by just running my code?)

```
STR.W R8, [R3], #4
STR.W R8, [R3], #4
STR.W R8, [R3], #4
STR.W R8, [R3], #4
STR.W R8, [R3], #4
STR.W R8, [R3], #4
STR.W R8, [R3]
```

I know that each instruction would load a value of R3 into R8 make an increment by 4 to R3 but what I am confused is that at the end of these instuctions what's the value containing in R8?

Is it [R3 + 16]? or it is [R3+4], [R3+8], ..., [R3+16]?

Comment: *would load a value of R3 into R8* is wrong.  It is backwards for `STR`; **would store a value to the R3 address from R8**.  This looks like some `memset()` type code.  Single step in a debugger.

Comment: @BitBank what makes you say 16 bits?

Comment: @BitBank: I think `STR.W` is a *Thumb2* instruction encoding?  I think they store 32bits.  Otherwise, it would be `STRH`?  The OP is not exactly clear on which mode they are in.

Comment: @artless, good point, I'm so used to working in ARM 32-bit mode and 68K asm that I confused the 2. Good catch. Info deleted...

Comment: @artlessnoise Indeed, the UAL `.W` qualifier forces a 32-bit (wide) encoding for the instruction, or an error if none is available. Similarly, `.N` forces a 16-bit (narrow) encoding (always an error in ARM mode).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
STR.W R8, [R3], #4
```

This instruction stores the 32-bit value held in `r8` to the address held in `r3`.  It then adds the immediate value `4` to `r3`.

```
A8.6.195 STR (register)

Store Register (register) calculates an address from a base register value
and an offset register value, stores a word from a register to memory. The
offset register value can optionally be shifted. For information about memory
accesses see Memory accesses on page A8-13.

Encoding T2     ARMv6T2, ARMv7
STR<c>.W <Rt>,[<Rn>,<Rm>{,LSL #<imm2>}]

STR<c><q> <Rt>, [<Rn>], <Rm>{, <shift>}    Post-indexed: index==FALSE, wback==TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

> what's the value containing in R8?

Always the same value, you didn't change it. You're always changing the memory value pointed by R3.

Reviewing the code:

```
STR.W R8, [R3], #4 /* *r3 ← r8 then r3 ← r3 + 4 */
```

Just as ARM documentation says:

> STR{type}{cond} Rt, [Rn], #offset           ; post-indexed

Another thing would be:

```
STR.W R8, [R3, +#4] /* *r3 ← r8 + 4 */
```

> STR{type}{cond} Rt, [Rn {, #offset}]        ; immediate offset

At last:

```
STR.W R8, [R3, #4]! /* r3 ← r3 + 4 then *R3 ← R8 */
```

> STR{type}{cond} Rt, [Rn, #offset]!          ; pre-indexed

I hope your doubt were on this direction.

Regards.